# random variable takes only rational values with probability one

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have found an old exercise that seems very interesting: let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be i.i.d. bernoullian random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0) = 1/2$. Define $S_{n} := X_{1} + ... + X_{n}$. It is to show that the random variable

$$
M := \sup_\limits{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{S_{n}}{n}
$$
with probability $1$ only takes rational values in the intervall $(1/2,1]$. Anyone has an idea, how to prove it?

Comment: The idea is that $S_n/n$ is going to assume some values greater than $1/2$ for some $n$ (with probability $1$) but then will tend to $1/2$ eventually, still with probability $1$, so the maximum is obtained for a finite value of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma** Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ be a mapping such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = c \in (0,1)$ exists. Then $$M := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n)$$ satisfies $$M \in \{c\} \cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap [c,1]).$$

*Proof:* Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = c$ we clearly have $M \geq c$. If $M=c$ we are done, and therefore we will from now assume that $M>c$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=c<M$ we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $f(n) < M$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus, $$M = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n) = \max_{n=1,\ldots,N} f(n).$$ This shows that the supremum is attained for some $n \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$ and so $M=f(n) \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

---

By the strong law of large numbers, we can apply the above lemma to $f(n) := S_n(\omega)/n$ with $c:=1/2$. This proves the assertion.

Comment: Ah, seems that I was way to slow...

Answer (score 2):

To add to Arnaud Mortier's comment: the fact that with probability $1$, $S_n/n \to 1/2$ as $n \to \infty$ comes from the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

The fact that with probability $1$, $S_n/n > 1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ is a consequence of  the Law of the Iterated Logarithm.

Comment: You don't need anything as strong as the law of iterated logarithm. Just use symmetry of the associated random walk and apply kolmogorov 0-1.

Comment: @Shalop That was my initial idea too, but it's not immediately obvious that this is a tail event.

Comment: Sure it is. On one hand, $S_n/n$ is either strictly larger or strictly smaller than $1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ (since it can't be exactly $1/2$ for odd $n$). Then by the union bound, at least one of those two events have probability at least $1/2$. But by symmetry, they have the same probability.

Comment: My point is that whether $S_n/n > 1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ can be affected by $X_1, \ldots, X_m$, so this event is not obviously in the tail field.

Comment: Sorry, I guess Hewitt savage would be more easily applicable in this case.

Comment: Yes, the Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law would do it.